# Пример программы (привязка данных)

Tags: c#, wpf

Тут [Пример привязки данных](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms771319) содержится пример программы на WPF. Если у кого будет время и терпение объясните каким образом в ListBox который находится в MainWindow привязали данные и отображают их в новых ListBox.
В частности: в MainWindow содержатся строки

```
<CollectionViewSource 
 Source="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=AuctionItems}"   
 x:Key="listingDataView" />
```

и

```
<ListBox Name="Master" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="8"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listingDataView}}">
     <ListBox.GroupStyle>
          <GroupStyle 
             HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource  groupingHeaderTemplate}"/>
     </ListBox.GroupStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Насколько понял привязка происходит следующим образом: строка `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listingDataView}}"` привязывает ресурс с именем `x:Key="listingDataView"` (пример кода выше). В нем (`x:Key="listingDataView"`), в свою очередь идет привязка к `Path=AuctionItems` реализованный в `DataBindingLabApp`
где содержится информация о товарах, отрисовка ListBox и т.д. Подскажите верно или нет?)

Comment: Вроде всё верно